# Swagger responds with TypeError: failed to fetch when redirecting to a working url

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, facebook-graph-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following code:

```cs
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize ()
        {
            var url = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id={appID}&state={state}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}k&scope=email";
            return Redirect(url);
        }
```

I'm using it to get user's info through external facebook auth.If I enter the same link through browser,it works and returns proper json.Redirecting to it doesn't work some reason and swagger responds with `TypeError:Failed to fetch` .
So far I tried

Removing app.UseHttpsRedirection()

Changing `Redirect(url)` to `new RedirectResult(url,true)`(as well as changing the return type of the method)

none of which worked.
Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: `TypeError:Failed to fetch` indicates that you tried to fetch the URL in the background (or Swagger UI did it for you), via an AJAX/fetch request. Which you of course can not do. Users need to be send to this URL _directly_, so that they can verify via their browser's address bar, that they are indeed sending their credentials to Facebook, and not some phishing site.

Comment: @CBroe So I have to leave routing to that link to front end app right?

Comment: To use Facebook as an identity provider, I think you'll need to define Facebook as a security scheme for your API. In OpenAPI YAML it would be [defined like this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/); your .NET framework (Swashbuckle?) might have similar annotations or configs. Also you'll probably need to register your API/app as an OAuth client in Facebook to get a client ID and to specify the allowed `redirect_uri`.